# Twillio Restclient in python

Tags: python, variables, sms, twilio

I'm Using Twilio Rest API in python to send sms , Below is the code I'm using to send SMS

SMS was being sent successfully by below code but I want body of text to be declared as a variable. For example if I declare `ABC = "Test message"` then body should be `Test message`.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
AUTH_TOKEN = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

message = client.messages.create(
    body="Hello World!",  
    to="+12125551234",
    from_="+15105551234",
)
print message.sid
```

If I use body = "ABC" it's sending message as "ABC" by sms i want declare variable in this case ABC = "Test Message " i want Body as Testmessage

```
message = client.messages.create(
    body="Hello Monkey!",  # Message body, if any
    to="+12125551234",
    from_="+15105551234",
)
print message.sid
```

Is there any way to send declare variable as Message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi if you write anything in a "" (string) then it will be treated as a String. You should modify your code like below:

```
text =  "Test Message"
message = client.messages.create(
    body= text,
    to="+12125551234",
    from_="+15105551234",
)
print message.sid
```

Basically you should assign the variable `text` to `body` so now body is "Test Message"

Comment: I felt so dumb how i missed this simple logic, Code is working Fine Now. Thanks Ankitha :)